# Problem with ColumnTransformer. DataFrame column ordering changes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I try to use SimpleImputer in specifics columns of my DataFrame and then use this preprocesing on a pipeline. I got this dataframe:

[image]

Then this is my solution:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

siFreq = SimpleImputer(
    missing_values=np.nan,  
    strategy='most_frequent',  
    verbose=0,
    copy=True
)

siZeros = SimpleImputer(
    missing_values=np.nan,  
    strategy='constant',  
    fill_value=0,
    verbose=0,
    copy=True
)

fet_zeros = ['NUM_COURSES_BEGINNER_DATASCIENCE','NUM_COURSES_ADVANCED_DATASCIENCE','NUM_COURSES_BEGINNER_BACKEND',\
             'NUM_COURSES_ADVANCED_BACKEND','NUM_COURSES_BEGINNER_FRONTEND','NUM_COURSES_ADVANCED_FRONTEND']

fet_freq = ['HOURS_DATASCIENCE','HOURS_BACKEND','HOURS_FRONTEND','AVG_SCORE_DATASCIENCE',\
            'AVG_SCORE_BACKEND','AVG_SCORE_FRONTEND']

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
transformers = [('si_zeros', siZeros, fet_zeros),
 ('si_freq', siFreq, fet_freq)],
remainder='passthrough')

#New DataFrame
df_data_3 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    data=column_trans.fit_transform(df_data_2),
    columns=df_data_2.columns  # las columnas originales deben conservarse en esta transformación
)
```

Now, the problem is that column ordering changes in the new DataFrame. Look:

[image]

I found a "solution" changing dis:

```
data=column_trans.fit_transform(df_data_2)[:,[6,7,8,0,2,4,1,3,5,9,10,11,12]],
```

Look:

[image]

But, now I got another big problem when I try to pipeline ColumnTransformer because data will proccess in a wrong way.